# Get Network Peers and Node type

Tags: polkadot, kusama

Is there an API to get the complete Peer List with what type of node it is from somewhere in the Polkadot/Kusama networks?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this calls. Not sure how it's formatted
https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/#syncstate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).